# Win 7 Documents & Programs Disappeared Suddenly - Hard Drive Space Increased

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, google-chrome

All of my documents and programs have disappeared, including desktop icons and wallpaper. I had 60gb available in c: now I have 400gb available.

Previous actions before problem - I completed a windows update, then enabled windows defender from services.msc (i had disabled it previously), my chrome was playing up so I uninstalled it using wise program uninstaller which also did a scan for any related entries, it found many and I deleted them (deletion process took at least 5mins). I then re-installed chrome.

Few hours later I realized my documents folder was empty, I restarted the computer and saw that the desktop icons were now gone, there is nothing left in the start menu either.

In the win 7 repair options screen it displays windows 8 OS (i previously upgraded to win 8 and downgraded to win 7 using windows own upgrade system)

Virus, corrupt user profile or got to do with previous win 8 installation?

Comment: So the free space has somehow 'reduced' from 60GB to 400GB?

Comment: If you lost files and free space is now 10x larger how was free space reduced?

Comment: No it has 'increased', typo error by myself

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue once before where **one** file added 1PB (Yes, PetaByte) to the HardDrive. Of course it was unuseable but nonetheless, I would recommend running [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to see if this is also the case for you. If there's a single file adding 300+GB WinDirStat makes it pretty noticeable. Obviously, you want to delete it but you're probably going to need to use a specific command to delete a huge/corrupt file. If that's the case, get back to us.

As for the missing documents, that symptom reeks of Malware. I've seen it too many times. Try running [Unhide](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/unhide/) or [Shadow Explorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/) to either Find or quickly recover them.

It's not likely a corrupt user profile since that usually results in not being able to even log into the User. As for the installation of Win7/8, I'm confused. You upgraded from Win7 to Win8, then "upgraded" (you mean downgraded?) later on afterward?

Comment: I previously upgraded to win 8 and then downgraded back to win 7 using windows own upgrade system.

Have just tried running Unhide and also Combofix, but nothing has changed, still no documents or programmes, still 340gb missing.

Also getting "oxc000000e Boot failed-required device is inaccessible" at boot up, have to bypass using repair disk

Comment: When using win7 repair disk, cmd is giving the default directory as X: rather than C: and when browsing computer for a system restore image, I can see that My Computer directory shows an x: drive, d: drive and the recovery drive, there is no C: ....not sure if this is normal?

Comment: Since you're booting from an external, repair disc, the drive is normally going to be `X:` As for the other drives, normally `C:` will still show up but seeing as how your situation isn't "normal" it doesn't really surprise me. You should try `diskmgmt.msc` or `diskpart` > `list disk` > `list volume` to see if your `C:` drive is still available but being listed as another letter. Also, if you're having BSOD's on startup I recommend running a 3rd party HDD scan like HDAT2, MHDD, Hiren's Boot CD, etc... Or at least run a `chkdsk`, `sfc /scannow`  or Startup Repair > http://tinyurl.com/37abfsf

Comment: System repair shows D: as the main OS parititon >  http://tinypic.com/r/2pycm6t/8 and this is what list volume shows > http://tinypic.com/r/24n3edt/8 I am sure that my main OS was installed on C: and my OS was Win7 not Win8. Appreciate your time. Thanks